# Importing C++ project in Xcode

Tags: c++, linux, xcode, makefile, cmake

How do I import a C/C++ project(NS3, GNU-Radio) to Xcode 7? The main reason I want to do this is to get autocompletion and Quick Help  definitions. This can be done in Eclipse by:

```
File > New > 'Makefile Project with existing code'
```

It would be nice to have the debugger working as well but not necessary

*The answers I have found are mostly for Xcode 4 and seem not to work on Xcode 7*

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to drag and drop all files of the Sources folder into project Navigator of XCode directly from the file browser. That will pop up a wizard to import files into the project. At this point you will need to check the application name into the "add to target" field. Failure to do this would include the files into the project but without actually compiling them.

You do not need to update the include path because the Wizard has already do that for you.

Here is an example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fqovf9OghSM under OSX if it helps :)